# IOS 5.0 ADDPlus implementation issue-

Tags: ios

When i am trying to implement  share through  AddPlus , following  error displayed. what can i do? Anybody knows?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libAddThis.a(ATFacebook.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ATReachability", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libAddThis.a(ATGenericUtility.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJSON", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libAddThis.a(ATTwitter.o)
  objc-class-ref in libAddThis.a(ATWebServiceAPI.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all your frameworks are properly referenced ? if I am not mistaken the following are required for addThis:

```
Security.framework,
CoreData.framework,
SystemConfiguration.framework,
MessageUI.framework,
Twitter.framework,
```

the following are needed for the new facebook SDK also set them as optional for versions prior to ios6

```
Social.framework,
AdSupport.framework,
Accounts.framework
```